# Keep object in center when zooming?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I've build my website using Wordpress (booo, i know) and I have a sticky menu (Menu from **Elementor Pro**, sticky header plugin from **Sticky Menu (or Anything!) on Scroll**) that always is showing on the top of the screen when you scroll.

To center this menu i've used custom CSS to the menu-element:

`

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

`

The problem is if i zoom in the browser, the menu gets off center the more i zoom. Until i refresh the page and it pops back in center.

Is there a way with CSS to keep the scaling and center of an object the whole time so it updates as i zoom. I want it always the same size, always in the center.

https://www.loom.com/share/fd55196094f942e98b800fcec7250228 Here is a videolink of the problem.

I've tried using:

`

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

`
It centers the block but when i zoom in or out, it jumps out of center until i refresh the page.

Website URL is https://visopro.se/

Comment: Hello, I understand
It is better to give the site address so that I can send exactly what you want

Comment: @MortezaBarati The website is VisoPro.se